# How do I show a message before redirect

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Im saving an employee to the database

when that succeeded i want to show a message to the user
i created a method to do so:

```
<div class="MessagePanelDiv">
    <asp:Panel ID="Message" runat="server" Visible="False">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        <asp:Label ID="LabelTypeMessage" CssClass="messageType" runat="server" />&nbsp;<asp:Literal ID="LiteralMessage" runat="server" />
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

With the javscript:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     window.setTimeout(function () {
         $(".alert").fadeTo(1500, 0).slideUp(500, function () {
             $(this).remove();
         });
     }, 3000);
 });
```

and the ShowMessage() method in Code-Behind:

```
public void ShowMessage(String message, WarningType type)
{
    //temp var to store the message type
    String MessageType;

    //gets the controls from the page
    Panel PanelMessage = this.FindControl("Message") as Panel;
    Label LiteralTypeMessage = PanelMessage.FindControl("LabelTypeMessage") as Label;
    Literal LiteralMessage = PanelMessage.FindControl("LiteralMessage") as Literal;

    //switch case to properly set the message type
    switch (type.ToString())
    {
        case "Succes":
            MessageType = "Success!";
            break;
        case "Info":
            MessageType = "Info!";
            break;
        case "Warning":
            MessageType = "Waarschuwing!";
            break;
        case "Danger":
            MessageType = "Fout!";
            break;
        default:
            MessageType = "";
            break;
    }

    //sets the message and the type of alert, than displays the message
    LiteralTypeMessage.Text = MessageType;
    LiteralMessage.Text = " " + message;
    PanelMessage.CssClass = String.Format("alert alert-{0} alert-dismissable", type.ToString().ToLower());
    PanelMessage.Attributes.Add("role", "alert");
    PanelMessage.Visible = true;
}
```

Now when the Employee is saved i call:

```
ShowMessage(GetGlobalResourceObject("Global.errors", "SaveSuccess").ToString(), WarningType.Success);
```

to show the message. this works fine but im implementing new pages so now i redirect after Employee is inserted.

My Question: How do i show a message to the user when the Employee is added, before it postback OR how can i show the message on the page the user is redirected to

Comment: You can display a message before redirecting the user using javascript. Easy to implement if you are using ajax for posting to your controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i edited my function ShowMessage to accept 3 vars

```
ShowMessage(String message, WarningType type, String redirect)
```

and updated the method:

```
LiteralTypeMessage.Text = MessageType;
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(redirect) || redirect == ""){
        LiteralMessage.Text = " " + message;
    }
    else{
        LiteralMessage.Text = " " + message + ", <script>window.setTimeout(function () { $('.alert').fadeTo(1500, 0).slideUp(500, function() {$(this).remove();});window.location = '" + redirect + "'}, 3000);</script>";
    }

PanelMessage.CssClass = String.Format("alert alert-{0} alert-dismissable", type.ToString().ToLower());
PanelMessage.Attributes.Add("role", "alert");
PanelMessage.Visible = true;
```

So when String redirect is empty it just shows the message

But when its not it shows the message and redirects to the page

Comment: this did it for me but i can accept it as an awnser after 2 days

Comment: One downside thou, now when the employee is saved the user remains on the edit page for a few seconds before redirecting. this is not desirable. when i finish the code to: save, redirect and show message ill upload it.